# Text over image is moving with the image, not seperately

Tags: html, css

I want the text written on my banner image to come down from the top, but when I do that with margin-top the banner portion from the top is coming down with it and the text is stuck on the top.

[image: Image with problem highlighted]

This is my code, help will be appreciated!

```css
.banner-image-main {
  height: 294px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://www.quackit.com/html/templates/download/bootstrap/business-1/images/light_bulb.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.banner-text-and-button {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire pr-2"></span><span>LOGO</span></div>
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Product</li>
    <li>
      <select>
        <option value="">Services</option>
        <option value="">Engage</option>
        <option value="">Pontificate</option>
        <option value="">Synergize</option>
      </select>
    </li>
    <li>My Account</li>
    <li> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart pr-2"></span>My Cart</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="banner-image-main">
  <div class="banner-text-and-button">
    <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer"></span>Dramatically Engage</h1>
    <p>Objectively innovate empowered manufactured products whereas parallel platforms.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" style="margin-left:12px;">Engage Now</a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just lower the text of the image you can add

```css
.banner-text-and-button {
    padding-top: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of a strange quirck called [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). Because I can't see your complete code, I'm a little hesitant to give you a simple code answer, but adding a padding-top of 1 pixel to `.banner-text-and-button` already fixes the problem.

I'd suggest reading up on the linked article and decide what's the best solution for you.

Comment: ok let me show u the rest of the classes so you can get a complete understanding.

.navbar-default {
            background-color: white;
            border-color: #e7e7e7;
            height:50px;
            border:none;
            width:95%;
            display:flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

       
        a {
            background-color:#333;
        }
        .navbar-brand{

           padding:15px 15px;
            float:left;
            height:50px;
            font-size:18px;
            margin-left:30px;

        }

Comment: @ubaidqureshi Add the margin you want to the `.banner-image-main` as `padding-top`. Should do the trick.

Comment: yes it did! thank you for your help, it's highly appreciated!

Comment: @ubaidqureshi No problem! You can help others who share your problem by upvoting and/or accepting this answer (with the checkmark on the left) so others see this is the answer to your question!

Comment: i loved to do so! thank you again!